# Solving relative velocity without Lorentz transform

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, relative-motion, time-dilation, length-contraction

> A train with proper length $L$ moves at speed $\frac{5c}{13}$ with respect to the
>   ground. A ball is thrown from the back of the train to the front. The speed of the ball
>   with respect to the train is $\frac{c}{3}$.As viewed by someone on the ground, how much time does the ball spend in the air, and how far does it travel?

All books give the solution to this/similar problems using the Lorentz transform equations. Can someone give a solution simply using the fundamental effects (length contraction, time dilation, and loss of simultaneity)?

Also, I prefer an approach different from the velocity addition one.

Comment: The Lorentz transformations are used to derive length contraction & time dilation, so using those formulae seem to amount to doing the same thing with the Lorentz transformation, no?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are clocks at the front and back of the train, at rest relative to the train and synchronized (using the [Einstein synchronization convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation)) in the train's frame. And suppose that as the ball is thrown from the back of the train, the clock there reads t=0. Using the train frame's definition of simultaneity, the clock at the front also reads t=0 when the ball is thrown, and both clocks are ticking at a normal rate in this frame, so if the ball moves at c/3 relative to the train and the train has length L in this frame, the time for the ball to reach the front must be 3L/c, so the clock at the front reads t=3L/c when the ball reaches it.

Now look at things in the ground frame. Aside from the length contraction and time dilation formulas, a useful formula to know is that if two clocks are synchronized in their own rest frame and have a distance L apart in that frame, then in the frame of an observer sees them moving at velocity v (along the same axis that joins them at any instant), at any given moment in the observer's frame the time on the clock in the rear will be ahead of the time on the clock in the front by $vL/c^2$ due to the relativity of simultaneity. So in this case, if the ground observer sees the train moving at (5/13)c, the ground observer always sees the clock at the back as ahead of the clock at the front by (5/13)cL/c^2 = (5/13)L/c. Thus in the ground frame, at the same moment the back clock reads t=0, the front clock reads t=-(5/13)L/c. So if the front clock reads t=3L/c = (39/13)L/c when the ball reaches it, the ground observer must say that the front clock ticked forward by the amount ((39+5)/13)L/c = (44/13)L/c between the moment the ball was thrown from the back and the moment it reached the front. But due to time dilation, the ground observer says the time $\Delta T$ in his own frame needed for a given clock on the train to tick forward by $\Delta \tau$ is given by the equation $\Delta T = \Delta \tau / \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$, and if the train is moving at v=(5/13)c then $\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$ works out to 12/13, so this means the time in the ground observer's frame for the ball to get from back to front is ((44/13)L/c)/(12/13) which works out to (11/3)L/c.

In the ground observer's frame, the train's length is (12/13)L due to length contraction. So if we imagine the back of the train starts at position X=0 at time T=0 in the ground frame at the moment the ball is thrown, the front must be at X=(12/13)L at T=0, so the position of the front as a function of time must be given by X(T) = (5/13)cT + (12/13)L. Treating the ball's velocity V in this frame as an unknown, the ball's position as a function of time X(T) = VT. So the ball will meet the front of the train at the value of T such that VT = (5/13)cT + (12/13)L, implying V = (5/13)c + (12/13)L/T. But we already know from before that in the ground frame, if the ball is thrown at T=0 then the value of T where the ball reaches the front must be T=(11/3)L/c, so we can plug that in to get V = (5/13)c + (12/13)(3/11)c = (55/143)c + (36/143)c = (91/143)c = (7/11)c. So, the ball's velocity in the ground frame is (7/11)c, which is also what you'd get from the velocity addition formula.

Since we've found both the time T it took in the ground frame to get from back to front, (11/3)L/c, and the velocity V of the ball in the ground frame as it traveled, (7/11)c, the answer to the "how far does it travel" question is simply VT = (7/3)L.